# SQL Multiple OR BETWEENS

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am working on Postgres and the following query never seems to finish executing, but it is only the final OR that causes a problem, it runs fine if I comment it out. Is it just that it is an inefficient way to write it? If so I can't think of an alternative.

```
SELECT a.subject_id, a.hadm_id, a.admittime, d.icd9_code, l.short_title, d.seq_num
FROM mimiciii.admissions a
INNER JOIN mimiciii.diagnoses_icd d
ON  a.subject_id = d.subject_id
AND a.hadm_id = d.hadm_id
INNER JOIN mimiciii.d_icd_diagnoses l
ON d.icd9_code = l.icd9_code
WHERE a.subject_id IN
    (SELECT DISTINCT d.subject_id
     FROM mimiciii.diagnoses_icd d
     WHERE d.icd9_code BETWEEN '390%' and '459%')
     AND d.icd9_code NOT IN 
     (SELECT d.icd9_code
         FROM mimiciii.diagnoses_icd d
         WHERE d.icd9_code BETWEEN 'V01%' AND 'V91%'
         OR d.icd9_code BETWEEN 'E000%' AND 'E999%'
         OR d.icd9_code BETWEEN '630%' AND '679%'
         OR d.icd9_code BETWEEN '760%' AND '999%'
          )
ORDER BY subject_id, admittime
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why is there need for a subquery at all?

wont this return what you want ?

```
SELECT a.subject_id, a.hadm_id, a.admittime, d.icd9_code, l.short_title,     d.seq_num
FROM mimiciii.admissions a
INNER JOIN mimiciii.diagnoses_icd d
ON  a.subject_id = d.subject_id
AND a.hadm_id = d.hadm_id
INNER JOIN mimiciii.d_icd_diagnoses l
ON d.icd9_code = l.icd9_code

WHERE  d.icd9_code BETWEEN '390%' and '459%' 
and not (d.icd9_code BETWEEN 'V01%' AND 'V91%') 
and not (d.icd9_code BETWEEN 'E000%' AND 'E999%')
and not (d.icd9_code BETWEEN '630%' AND '679%')
and not (d.icd9_code BETWEEN '760%' AND '999%')     
ORDER BY subject_id, admittime
```

Or am I mistaken somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps one reason it never finishes execution because the `BETWEEN`s filter *all* rows out.  You cannot use wildcards with `BETWEEN`.

That entire subquery seems unnecessary.  You can just remove it.  Try this `where` clause:

```
WHERE a.subject_id IN (SELECT d.subject_id
                       FROM mimiciii.diagnoses_icd d
                       WHERE d.icd9_code >= '390' and 
                             d.icd9_code < '460'
                      )
```

If a code matches this, then it does not match your other conditions.

I suspect that there are other issues with the query, but this one is glaring.

Comment: @Sam . . . They are not doing what you think they are doing.  They are not wildcards; they are just the `'%'`, which is really  misleading to anyone reading the query (including you in the future).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.subject_id, a.hadm_id, a.admittime, d.icd9_code, l.short_title, d.seq_num
FROM mimiciii.admissions a
INNER JOIN mimiciii.diagnoses_icd d
ON  a.subject_id = d.subject_id
AND a.hadm_id = d.hadm_id
INNER JOIN mimiciii.d_icd_diagnoses l
ON d.icd9_code = l.icd9_code
WHERE a.subject_id IN
    (SELECT DISTINCT d.subject_id
     FROM mimiciii.diagnoses_icd d
     WHERE d.icd9_code BETWEEN '390%' and '459%')
     AND d.icd9_code NOT IN 
     (SELECT d.icd9_code
         FROM mimiciii.diagnoses_icd d
         WHERE (d.icd9_code BETWEEN 'V01%' AND 'V91%')
         OR (d.icd9_code BETWEEN 'E000%' AND 'E999%')
         OR (d.icd9_code BETWEEN '630%' AND '679%')
         OR (d.icd9_code BETWEEN '760%' AND '999%')
          )
ORDER BY subject_id, admittime
```

You could try (haven't tested it) using brackets to order the subquery in this case it will evaluate the brackets first then run the OR statement to collect the data to feed into the outer query.

Comment: Thank you, putting brackets around brought back the wrong results, but the comment above did work.